# Fit to Binomial Function

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, distributions, data

I have the following data, and need to fit a binomial distribution to this data. I have already done so for a gaussian fit (this is the example code I have below), but I am having trouble using a binomial distribution.

For this data, n = 18 and p = 1/2.

```
data := {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 5}, {6, 4}, {7, 11}, {8, 
24}, {9, 18}, {10, 20}, {11, 9}, {12, 6}, {13, 0}, {14, 0}, {15, 
1}, {16, 0}, {17, 0}, {18, 0}}

model[x_] = ampl Evaluate[PDF[NormalDistribution[x0, sigma], x]];
fit = FindFit[data, model[x], {ampl, x0, sigma}, x]
Show[ListPlot[data], 
Plot[model[x] /. fit, {x, 0, 19}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
AxesLabel -> {"# of Heads", "# of Trials"}]
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to obtain the estimate of the probability of a head ($p$):

```
data = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 5}, {6, 4}, {7, 11}, {8, 24},
  {9, 18}, {10, 20}, {11, 9}, {12, 6}, {13, 0}, {14, 0}, {15, 1}, {16, 0}, 
  {17, 0}, {18, 0}};
n = 18;
p = data[[All, 1]].data[[All, 2]]/(n Total[data[[All, 2]]])
(* 97/200 *)  (* Very close to 0.5 *)
```

I've added in a zero count for when there are zero heads.

One can plot the observed relative frequencies and the estimated probabilities for a binomial distribution:

```
DiscretePlot[{data[[All, 2]][[k + 1]]/Total[data[[All, 2]]], 
  PDF[BinomialDistribution[18, p], k]}, {k, 0, 18}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Observed relative frequencies", "Estimated binomial distribution"},
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, AxesLabel -> {"# of Heads", "Probability"}]
```

[image: Binomial distributions]